# After a while, Apache stops serving until it's restarted

Tags: apache, ispconfig

Using ISPConfig 3, Apache 2.

I click around a few pages on my website. After a while, pages won't load anymore. It's just stuck with loading. Doesn't matter what kind of file, PHP, HTML, txt.

Restart apache with `service apache2 restart` helps, but it stops again after a while.

Comment: Have you taken a look to the apache error log?

Comment: Also the process list might be a good thing to look into.